# How to find a particular value from whole database in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a very large data base. and want to find a value but i am not sure about column name. Is there any way to find that value from whole database irrespective of column names.

Waiting for your response

Tanu

Comment: You are going to have to tell us more than this.

Comment: try select * from sysobjects and find which tables you need to search..try also the links of @Bilal.from MSDN

Comment: what do you mean by sysobjects

Answer (score 3):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/112b8dd8-fb1f-4c73-b61c-68919bbd5bc5

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm